# Getting 99.7% accuracy on google colab but only 4% on my PC using same code

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN model to recognize 28 different classes. 
Here's my model:

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And here's epoch and everything else:

```
model, callbacks_list = cnn_model()
    model.summary()
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels), epochs=20, batch_size=500, callbacks=callbacks_list)
    scores = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=0)
```

The problem is when I train this model on my PC, I get accuracy of 3-5% approx. However, When trained on google colab, I get 99.57% accuracy.

My PC packages and stuff:

```
python 3.6.8
tensorflow 1.13.1
keras 2.2.4
```

All I did was upload everything on google colab and test for a surprising result.

Comment: Are you using same code for training in local and colab.? same pre-processing.? same data.? Training gives same loss on both cases.?

Comment: Exactly the same. Didn't change as much a semicolon. Just uploaded the whole folder on colab and trained there.

Comment: So you are getting same loss while training in both cases.?

Comment: 99.57% accuracy over 28 different classes is too difficult to achieve. There is probably something wrong on colab training

Comment: Well, I tested the model with my own captured images and colab does recognize almost all the time whereas model from my PC keeps printing the same class. Loss is different too I think.  @sreeram TP

Comment: As @IoannisNasios have mentioned that kind of accuracy is not that easy to achieve especially with a shallow model like yours. Of course, it depends on the data. I recommend you to check the training and testing data in colab. I suspect there is some kind of leakage or something happening

Comment: I tested the trained model on the testing dataset that I have created and got similar accuracy. Not 99% but 83%. And got same 4% accuracy with home pc trained model. I can upload the full project on GitHub if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause.

It was due to a version difference between the environments.
The local Keras version had a strange bug tracked by this issue - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11376, which wasn't present in the version of Keras present in Google Colab.